# Live video streaming in 2017

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

Many years ago, we built a live streaming application with `Flash Media Server`. Meanwhile, `Flash` got obsolete and we'd like to upgrade to a `HTML5` solution.

Although I have found some answers on SO, but they seem a bit old. 
Therefore, I wonder **what is a good combo for video+audio live streaming nowadays (July 2017)?**

The requirements are pretty simple: one broadcaster and many viewers (100+) that are using various modern browsers (IE11+, Edge, Firefox, Chrome). Ideally, we'd like to use a open-source solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the wire I'd put DASH and HLS with AVC/AAC and then use HTML/JavaScript players. You can get a reference player here: http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/nightly/dash.js/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html

As far as servers - I'd try http://red5.org/

For authoring your live stream I'd try: https://obsproject.com/